# Android- How to send data from activity to service?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

In my application I'm trying to send data from my `MainActivity.class` to a service called `bgservice.class`. This is my following code:

MainActivity.class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(bgservice.class.getName());
  serviceIntent.putExtra("UserID", "123456");
  this.startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

bgservice.class:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

  String userID = intent.getStringExtra("userID");
  System.out.println(userID);
  Toast.makeText(this,userID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  return START_STICKY;

}
```

but I'm not getting the data in the service class. these are the following error I get:

> 02-25 09:05:41.166: E/AndroidRuntime(2633):
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.microapple.googleplace/com.microapple.googleplace.
>   MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must
>   be   explicit: Intent { act=com.microapple.googleplace.bgservice (has
>   extras) }

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
     ...
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >



        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".bgservice" />
</application>
....
```

Comment: have you added the service in your manifest?

Comment: ya i added @RandykaYudhistira

Comment: @Balau1: have you added `com.microapple.googleplace.bgservice` Action in manifest?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK u mean adding  <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".bgservice" /> in android manifest.xml file?

Comment: @Balau1 you are sending "UserID"and receiving "userID" that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
 Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(bgservice.class.getName());
```

Passing String to `Intent` constructor for creating Intent to start Service. Intent constructor takes String as a Action name which we have added in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".bgservice">
<intent-filter >
        <action android:name="com.microapple.googleplace.bgservice" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Now use `com.microapple.googleplace.bgservice` as action name to create Intent:

```
      Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.microapple.googleplace.bgservice");
      serviceIntent.putExtra("UserID", "123456");
      this.startService(serviceIntent);
```

**OR**

Use Intent constrictor which takes Context as first parameter and component name which we want to start as second parameter :

```
  Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this,bgservice.class);
  serviceIntent.putExtra("UserID", "123456");
  this.startService(serviceIntent);
```

And also use same key which using to add data in Intent currently adding value with `UserID` key but trying to get value using `userID` key

Comment: @Balau1: try it using `Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this,bgservice.class);`

Comment: @ prosper k : It works ! thanks for helping me . I changed the thing u said in manifest file and  used Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this,bgservice.class); i

Comment: @JerinAMathews: Use `onStartCommand` method for getting data from intent. like `int UserID= intent.getIntExtra("UserID",0);`

Answer (score 7):

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, bgservice.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("UserID", "123456");
        this.startService(serviceIntent);
```

And in your service,

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    String userID = intent.getStringExtra("UserID");

    //do something

    return START_STICKY;

}
```

This must work.

Comment: What can I do if I want to use userID variable in service's onCreate()  method?  Sorry for commenting answer from 2015.

Comment: You can get that variable in onCreate() as, `Intent intent = getIntent();`, `if(intent != null && intent.hasExtra("userID")){ String userID = intent.getExtra("userID") }`

Comment: getIntent() is not working in services how can i send parcelable data then

Comment: `getIntent()` does work in android service. Can you show me the way you're using it?