# Is there is a way to for activity to communicate a service which start the activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I have a service which have a callback function for detecting changes in the clipboard where the callback has a pendingIntent which is used by a notification and later notification used to start an activity once the notification is clicked.So here is my question, so is there is a possibility for the started activity to notify back to service once the activity is started (one way communication is just fine)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android- How to send data from activity to service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28710833/android-how-to-send-data-from-activity-to-service)

Answer (score 0):

You could send a broadcast `Intent` from the `Activity` to notify the `Service`. The `Service` should register a `BroadcastReceiver` that will be triggered by the broadcast `Intent`.